# Route complete TLD (*.dev for example) to 127.0.0.1

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

For development purposes I want all DNS requests to the .dev TLD to forward to my own PC.

The hosts file does not suffice. I use multiple domains and also multiple subdomains. I would have to add a line for each combination.

I have read that a DNS forwarder like DNSmasq can be used to do the job (for example [as described here](http://daniel.hahler.de/easy-dns-wildcard-setup-for-local-domains-using-dnsmasq)). Also this software is already installed on Ubuntu 12.10.

The problem is that I fail to see how and where I should configure DNSmasq, i.e., where I should put this line:

```
address=/dev/127.0.0.1
```

Comment: You may not want to use `.dev` as Google took it. I'm still researching what they'll use it for and whether they plan for regular people to connect to it or just employees, but you may not want to redirect all access in case it's the former, unless this is purely a test box that will never connect to external hosts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The complete standalone dnsmasq (DHCP and DNS server) is not installed by default in Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10, but a package called dnsmasq-base is installed by default in Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 and 12.10. The dnsmasq-base package contains the dnsmasq binary and is used by NetworkManager.

To do what you want you will need to use dnsmasq as a caching DNS server. You need to:

- Install dnsmasq
  sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
- Change your network setting, so that your computer uses itself as it dns server.
- Make the changes to the config files:

Create `/etc/dnsmasq.d/dev-tld` with these contents:

```
local=/dev/

address=/dev/127.0.0.5
```

The first command says `*.dev` requests can't be forwarded to your real DNS server. The second says `*.dev` resolves to `127.0.0.5` which is localhost.

- Restart the dnsmasq service (not network-manager)

Comment: Thank you! It was extremely helpfull that I got to known that the DNSMasq present was not the real deal. After installing the complete package and configuring it in the way I described before I got it to work. :)

Comment: I'd prefer [the other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/233224/88802) for recent desktop installations. For recent desktop installations you would be running two dnsmasq instances this way. Your answer could be very useful in non-NetworkManager setups, older ones (not using dnsmasq) or even server installations!

Comment: Yep, other answer is best since Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 22):

In Ubuntu 12.10 or later you can do this with dnsmasq as run by NetworkManager.

1. Create the directory `mkdir /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d` if it doesn't already exist.

   ```
   sudo mkdir /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
   ```
2. Toss the following line into `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dev-tld`.

   ```
   address=/dev/127.0.0.1
   ```
3. (Ubuntu 12.10) Restart NetworkManager.

   ```
   sudo service network-manager restart
   ```
4. (Ubuntu > 13.04) Restart Dnsmasq.

   ```
   sudo service dnsmasq restart
   ```
5. Enjoy the awesomeness.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to AbrahamVanHelpsing for the [link to the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnsmasq#NetworkManager) on how to do this.

Comment: After following your steps still I get to see "unknown host" after running a ping.

Do I need to configure/enable DNSMasq on some other place? Or configure my network properties in a different way? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. it's showing up fine for me.

Comment: Ah, @RoelvanDuijnhoven - are you running 12.10 or 12.04? Works fine for me on 12.10.

Comment: I am running 12.10. But I do need to mention that I have tried to alter some configuration file prior to asking a question here. Possibly these changes mitigate your solution. Javier Rivera's solution did the trick however!

Comment: This works! Any way to also handle ports? E.g accessing http://local.dev would make a request to 127.0.0.1:3000..

Comment: @epigene for that you'd need to setup a nginx or apache proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Just installed a fresh 19.04 and the only way I got it working was disabling `systemd-resolved` and have `NetworkManager` use `dnsmasq` instead for DNS. `NetworkManager` has built in support for `dnsmasq` and `dnsmasq-base` package is installed by default.

I am pointing multiple domains to different VMs like `*.customerX.test` to `192.168.33.10` and `*.productY.test` to `192.168.33.20` and so on. I would not use `*.dev` anymore but instead one of the [reserved top level domains](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-2).

#### Solution

1. Disable `systemd-resolved`

   ```
    sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
    sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service
    sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to use `dnsmasq` for DNS.

   ```
    [main]
    dns=dnsmasq
   ```
3. Put `dnsmasq` configuration in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/test-tld.conf`

   ```
    address=/test/127.0.0.1
    address=/customerX.test/192.168.33.10
   ```
4. and finally restart `NetworkManager` which will generate a new `/etc/resolv.conf`

   ```
    sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04:

1. Install `dnsmasq`

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y install dnsmasq
   ```
2. Edit `dnsmasq.conf` file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf
   ```
3. Add your command:

   ```
   address=/dev/127.0.0.1
   ```

   For wild card (*) then you can use dot (.) then dnsmasq to resolve 
   `WHATEWER_YOU_PUT_HERE.yourmachine.yourdomain` to the same ip. E.g., `address=/.localhost.dev/127.0.0.1`
4. Restart dnsmasq service:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
   ```