# Why does the default site for Apache in Ubuntu have “<Directory />”?

Tags: apache2

These are the contents of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

What is the following block for?

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That block applies to the root or `/` directory. Remember the syntax is `<Directory /path/to/files>`. In your example the path is `/`.

This means that any directory under `/` will have the rules: `Options FollowSymlinks` and `AllowOverride None` unless there is a rules that overrides it for a specific directory.

To understand what those directives mean check the [Apache Directives Index](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directives.html)

Comment: Could you help me with this one... http://askubuntu.com/questions/265300/how-do-i-setup-name-based-virtual-hosts-using-ubuntu-12-04