# Ubuntu 17.10 - Route complete TLD (*.dev for example) to 127.0.0.1

Tags: network-manager, dns, 17.10

I always used the solutions here, [Route complete TLD (*.dev for example) to 127.0.0.1](https://askubuntu.com/q/233195/348298) in my previous Ubuntu setups. But today after upgrading to 17 I am not able to make this work no matter what I try.

I installed all the released updates and bug-fixes. But can't make this work. Have you hit the same problem? I didn't do a single config yet, it's brand new install of Ubuntu.

- by default `dnsmasq` was not installed which I installed it and the status of the service is running
- I tried putting the config on these files `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`
   and also tried `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dev-tld` but none worked
- I did try these commands in both files `address=/dev/127.0.0.1`
   , `address=/.dev/127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dnsmasq` I went by editing `sudo nano ./hosts`.

Inside the file add a line similar to this

> 127.0.0.1 foo.dev

That's it, save the file and enjoy.

Comment: But you have to add a line for each subdomain. That does not route a complete tld.

Comment: right, it just temporarily solved my problem. Later on I understood that  problem was caused by google buying .dev tld and happened in  Chrome. so I switched my development tld to something else and it worked this time

Comment: I tried the same with *.tld but since NetworkManager use dnsmas-base, it doesn't work and I can't start dnsmasq service by hand :/ How do you achieve this ?

Comment: Okay that was just a problem on resolv.conf. It's allright now :)